# Return list of _all_ ip addresses using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Using the AWS CLI, I'd like to retrieve a list of *all* IP addresses, whether EIP or statically assigned etc.

I've been using describe-instances and describe-addresses but want to know if there is an easier way to get all public IP addresses?

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --public-ips --region eu-west-1 --query 'Addresses[*].PublicIp'

aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1
```

I've searched through the AWS documentation, but haven't found anything that encompasses everything.

Comment: What's wrong with the commands you posted?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the commands, but I want to know whether there is an _easier_ way to get a list of all public IP addresses in an AWS account rather than having to query each service. As an example, the commands listed won't cover AWS Workspaces and I wouldn't want to miss out on reporting for a service I might not be aware of.

Comment: _Why_ do you seek this information? Are you creating a whitelist?

Comment: @John I curate lists of our public IP address and regularly scan them to make sure that there aren't any services inadvertently exposed to the internet.

Comment: The above commands do not create a full list. The commands in the answer below are way more complete.

Comment: As to why... It is a good idea to port scan your perimeter periodically to find hosts and services that are listening that you might have forgotten about or someone else stood up for unknown reason. This is a part of good security practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will likely be able to retrieve most of the IP addresses from multiple services by calling the AWS EC2 ENI API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-network-interfaces.html

This will gather all IP addresses in for supported services and output them for you.

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query "NetworkInterfaces[*][].PrivateIpAddresses[*][].{Private: PrivateIpAddress, Public: Association.PublicIp}"
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "overall" command you could run. Each service has its own API.

Please note that many services will have IP addresses that change. For example, an Elastic Load Balancer will use many IP addresses and should always be addressed by its DNS Name rather than by IP address.